# Twig Eclipse plug-in syntax highlighting

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, twig

I need to develop with Eclipse a lot of twig view files, to be used with Symfony 2.
I'd like use syntax highlighting and code assist.

Then I installed the Twig Editor Feature 1.0.13 plugin by Dubture on my Eclipse.

It seems installed correctly , I see the new Twig Editor and it's associated to .twig files,
but it doesn't work:

- If a create a new Twig file, the template shown isn't the one documented on website, it's the standard one
- Syntax higlighting and code assist don't work at all: if I write {% block edit %} I see all text black

Comment: If you right click on the file and select 'Open With' is the Twig editor selected?

Comment: It shows a list of editors available, then I choose Twig Editor and it loads. But it doesnt't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was my eclipse workspace. Something went wrong with that.
I resolved by creating a new workspace and now I've got twig syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

For this neet to install twig plugin from marketplace or from eclipse official site https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/twig-plugin
and then change your workspace if it is not working